# Translate from C to C#

Tags: c#, c

I have been working on translating some code from C to C# but since I haven't been coding in C / C++ for many years now plus I do not want to resort to the unsafe keyword. I have made an attempt and would like some verification & optimisation suggestions.

Here is the code in C/C++.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus /* C++ cannot assign void* from malloc to *data */
#define APPEND_DATA(/* T */ value, /* T** */ data, /* size_t* */ size) {\
  if (!((*size) & ((*size) - 1))) {\
    /*double alloc size if it's a power of two*/\
    void** data_void = reinterpret_cast<void**>(data);\
    *data_void = (*size) == 0 ? malloc(sizeof(**data))\
                              : realloc((*data), (*size) * 2 * sizeof(**data));\
  }\
  (*data)[(*size)] = (value);\
  (*size)++;\
}
#else /* C gives problems with strict-aliasing rules for (void**) cast */
#define APPEND_DATA(/* T */ value, /* T** */ data, /* size_t* */ size) {\
  if (!((*size) & ((*size) - 1))) {\
    /*double alloc size if it's a power of two*/\
    (*data) = (*size) == 0 ? malloc(sizeof(**data))\
                           : realloc((*data), (*size) * 2 * sizeof(**data));\
  }\
  (*data)[(*size)] = (value);\
  (*size)++;\
}
#endif
```

Here is the code in C#:

```
public static T[] AppendData<T>(T value, T[] data, ref uint size)
{
    if ((size & (size - 1)) != 0)
    {
        /* Double alloc size if it's a power of two */
        var tsize = size == 0 ? data.Length : size*2*data.Length;
        var tdata = new T[tsize];
        Array.Copy(data, tdata, data.Length);
        tdata[size] = value;
        data = tdata;
    }
    else
    {
        data[size] = value;
    }

    size++;
    return data;
}
```

One more thing to note is that performance is paramount for this code as the overall algorithm it fits in to is quite slow.

Comment: Welcome! Feel free to post the entire algorithm if you like — context can make a big difference.

Comment: A new/modified compression algorithm by Google. Here is the link to it - https://code.google.com/p/zopfli/

Comment: My aim here is to refresh my C also to ensure that I am translating accurately. I am contending with ensuring the code works at the end and then I will optimise to ensure good performance and efficiency in c#.

Comment: I started writing some notes but got blocked a little in because I really need some content. What is the function meant to do exactly? It looks like you are implementing the add function for a dynamic array but the if and tsize calculations look a bit off. Is size the size taken up in the array by the data or is it something you're passing that determines the size of the new array?

Comment: If you are familiar with GitHub try cloning this  https://code.google.com/p/zopfli and checkout the zopfli.c & the gzip_contianer.c files.

Comment: zopfli.c was deleted but I can't find this function with the last version of it (https://code.google.com/p/zopfli/source/diff?spec=svn8c218eff39749e738c92bf34155099ad280c16f7&r=8c218eff39749e738c92bf34155099ad280c16f7&format=side&path=/zopfli.c) I can't see it in gzip_container.c either?

Comment: When translating code between two languages with completely different goals, it would be a disservice to attempt to do a line-by-line literal translation. You should utilize features of the language that you are translating to as they were meant to be used. Don't restrict yourself to having the translated code behave exactly like the old code, do what makes sense in the target language. In this case, define a class to encapsulate the array and the used size then add methods to handle resizing. Better yet, don't even bother reinventing the wheel, use a `List`, the work is already done for you.

Answer (score 1):

From a micro-optimization perspective I have found that C# and the JIT tend to like things from left to right ([post](http://mediocresoft.com/Blog/simple-readable-csharp-micro-optimization-expression-operand-ordering)).
Ex: `(((size - 1) & size) != 0)` and `data.Length*size*2`

With a macro and readability (verification) perspective I would be curious to see the performance difference between this method and just using `List<T>.Add`.

When it comes to performance you need to just measure it. On different machines if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Some notes, I may have some wrong because there isn't any context:

- In C# `uint` is generally avoided to prevent casting from `uint` to `int`, [the array [] operator actually takes an `int` for example.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494734.aspx) I know it feels more correct using `uint` but it just isn't better. Including `uint` in a public interface is also [not CLS compliant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhc3fa7f.aspx).
- It looks like you're implementing a dynamic array but isn't your `tsize` calculation incorrect? Shouldn't it be something more along the lines of this?

  ```
  var tsize = size == 0 ? data.Length : size * 2 * data.Length;
  ```

  In its current state it would always be doubling the array if there is an item present.

Answer (score 0):

### Wellcome in C# land!

You are trying to implement a dynamic array or something like that so why not to a List or another collection like Collection. These are dynamic sizeable no need to worry about size/space handling.

In C# do not be an array-oriented coder feel free to use other powerfull collections.